# What can run on a virtual console except getty and X?

Tags: linux, virtual-console

So I know about linux virtual consoles, about how you can access them with `ctrl+alt+f#`, and I know that consoles 1-6 run `getty` and console 7 typically runs an X server, but that got me thinking about what else can run on a virtual console? Is there a way to create software that would run on a virtual console? Are there any tools for that? Is there maybe a way to run a C program on a virtual console or something like that?

Comment: When you log in you get a normal (usually `bash`) shell from which you can run any command-line tool. You can also start a new X session, so you can support two or more independent users logged in simultaneously, though you will need plenty of memory for this. What more do you want?

Comment: @AFH I am talking more about the the 8-12 ones, they aren't running anything, what can they run? (maybe I wasn't clear)

Comment: No, you weren't clear. It's a while since I did it, but my recollection is that, when I started a second X session, this was accessible through `Ctrl-Alt-F8`, so in principle the F8 to F12 function keys could be used for up to five additional X sessions.

Comment: @AFH yeah I guess I am still not clear. Right now when I switch to tty8 for example, it's just a black screen. Typing doesn't do anything, `Ctrl-C` doesn't do anything, it basically is just there without running anything. I guess `getty` is what displays login/command promt, and it isn't running on it. My question is what can I run on it except for `getty` and an X server?

Comment: You can enable any number of virtual consoles, as described [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-7.html). Once you have logged in you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @AFH but "once you have logged in" is getty...

Comment: OK. I didn't see Amit Gold's answer when I made the comment and it seems to be exactly what you want. When I tested, it used one of the existing consoles until I added `-c 8`, though this may be a bug in Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: @AFH yeah, considering I am Amit Gold :D

Comment: I had kept this open in a browser tab, and for some reason it didn't flag a new answer, as it usually does. It was only when I read your comment that it was flagged, and I didn't check back over all the discussion before I quickly responded. Anyway, well done on finding the solution, one to bear in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sudo openvt`, a virtual console can run any script.